# Generic Class Loader: 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have many similar classes and I am trying to create a generic method that loads a list of objects of each class. I am not using any ORM, but just loading a SqlDataReader with the respective SQL Query.

I have tried using an interface and using generics.

I have simplified the problem below using only 2 short classes:

Interface:

```
public interface IMyEntity<T> where T : new()
{
    public List<T> ConvertToObjects(SqlDataReader dr);

    public static IMyEntity<T> CreateInstance() 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Class 1:

```
public class Cat : IMyEntity<Cat>
{   
    public long CatID { get; set; } 
    public string CatName { get; set; } 
    public int OwnerID { get; set; }

    public List<Cat> ConvertToObjects(SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        List<Cat> cats = new();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Cat cat = new()
                {
                    CatID = dr.GetInt32("CatID"),
                    CatName = dr.GetString("CatName"),
                    OwnerID = dr.GetInt32("OwnerID")
                };
                cats.Add(cat);
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        return cats;
    }

    public IMyEntity<Cat> CreateInstance()
    {
        IMyEntity<Cat> cat = new Cat();
        return cat;
    }
}
```

Class 2:

```
public class Dog : IMyEntity<Dog>
{
    public long DogID { get; set; }
    public string DogName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public List<Dog> ConvertToObjects(SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        List<Dog> dogs = new();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Dog dog = new()
                {
                    DogID = dr.GetInt32("DogID"),
                    DogName = dr.GetString("DogName"),
                    OwnerID = dr.GetInt32("Age")
                };
                dogs.Add(dog);
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        return dogs;
    }

    public IMyEntity<Dog> CreateInstance()
    {
        IMyEntity<Dog> dog = new Dog();
        return dog;
    }
}
```

And I have another class with this method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetObjectAsync<T>(string procedureName)
{
    if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) _connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new(procedureName, _connection);
    SqlDataReader dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    var myEntity = IMyEntity<T>.CreateInstance();
    IEnumerable<T> objs = myEntity.ConvertToObjects(dr);

    return objs;
}
```

The line with 'CreateInstance' is returning the following error: "'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'IMyEntity'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `T : new()` constraint is missing in the calling method’s own generic type.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetObjectAsync<T>(string procedureName)
```

Thus the compiler cannot guarantee the constraint requirement for the interface in `IMyEntity<T>` is met. It is not related to any specific method call and the restriction requirement comes from the interface definition itself.

```
public interface IMyEntity<T> where T : new()
```

Either remove the restriction from the interface — in which case `new T()` cannot be used — or add the restriction to the calling method’s generic type.

Comment: I removed the restriction from the interface, added to the calling method and the error is gone.
Now the problem is that when I call the method `IMyEntity<T>.CreateInstance();` it is calling the method from the interface and not from the concrete class.

Comment: Only need to remove *or* add the restriction.

Comment: The second issue is because the *static* method is called in the default interface. This *static* method has no relation to the *instance* methods defined in each concrete type. *A* “solution” that might be sought here is to 1) add the `new` restriction to *both* generic types; 2) *remove* the non-static methods in the implementations; 3) have the *static interface method* as `return new T()`

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps you were looking for a [*static abstract* interface method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/static-abstract-interface-methods) added in C#10 / .NET 6. In this case the methods in the concrete type must *also* be marked as *static* and there should be no body in the interface.